# SWIFT UIColor from Class method or Type method

Tags: objective-c, methods, swift, uicolor

In objective-c, we can write like this to call color with class method.

```
+ (UIColor *)getFromRGB:(int)red green:(int)green blue:(int)blue
{
    float r = (float)red / 255;
    float g = (float)green / 255;
    float b = (float)blue / 255;
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:1];
}
```

Then, we can call like this.

```
cell.backgroundColor = [Helpers getFromRGB:216 green:38 blue:56]
```

In Swift, I read from this and it is called Type method. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html

So, I try to write like this.

```
class Helper
{
    class func colorFromRGB (red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int) -> UIColor
    {
        var color: UIColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red/255), green: CGFloat(green/255), blue: CGFloat(blue/255), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
        return color
    }
}
```

But I got error like this when I call that Type method. How should I do?
[image]

Modified: it is not okay to call like that also. After that, I write like this without having red parameter like this according to xCode auto-suggestion. Then, I can compile but I only get black color like that. I think I am wrong in calling method and color information also wrong. How shall I do?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use labels for all arguments, you can specify the first argument's label with "`red red: ...`" or just "`#red: ...`":

```
class func colorFromRGB(#red: Int, green...
```

Or you might consider using an extension to define your own convenience initializer:

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat) {
        self.init(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

Then you can directly call `UIColor(red: ..., green: ..., blue: ...)`.

Comment: Thanks. I think I can call with argument with your suggestion. But I only have my color value as black only because of my division. It give 0.000000. How shall I do to correctly call my method?

Comment: @KhantThuLinn Why don't you just use `CGFloat` instead of `Int`?

Comment: oh...I change to CGFloat instead of Int and it is now okay. Thanks for your help. I don't know that I can't use Int and convert.

Comment: You can convert, but you need to use `CGFloat(red)/255` instead of `CGFloat(red/255)`.

Did you see my newly edited answer? I think an extension is better for your helper function...

Comment: Yes. I think I better use extension. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Swift forces to put parameter names (argument labels) for all parameters. Then you have to write something like this.

```
Helper.colorFromRGB(red: 3, green: 3, blue: 3)
```

This is not related to type method or `UIColor` specifically.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please check modified question? I try to call like that and it give me error.